# My address shown in Firefly starts with atoi1 instead of iota1

Tags: firefly

When I created a new wallet (or migrated an existing one) to Firefly, the address shown starts with `atoi1` and not `iota1`. Others cannot send funds to that address.

Answer (score 2):

This happened because when install the firefly wallet you activated the "developer" option.

You need create a new wallet without this option, when you do, the address will be start with "iota1"

Comment: This is true for the latest version (1.3.2). In previous versions it was possible to (accidentally) switch to devnet by adding devnet nodes to a non-developer profile. I know this because I still have two devnet profiles which got useless now as they do not accept their nodes any more.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are not connected to the devnet, but to the main net.

To change, open your account in Firefly, open "Network configuration" in advanced settings, and make sure that your node selection is set to Automatic.